# Link/button in emails (Rails) shows Heroku app url, not the correct website url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, actionmailer

I am using Rails Mailer + Heroku and all works, except that I have some links styled like buttons inside of the emails as follows:

```
%p.buttons
  = link_to "Agree", new_response_url(id: @some_id, decision: "agreed"), :class => "link", :target => "_blank"
```

Which also works fine, the only issue is it opens showing a herokuapp url e.g. rails-app.herokuapp.com, but I want it to be website url? Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify your domain in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }
```

This domain name will be used in your ActionMailer URLs.

---

For any case specify [only_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor/url_for) option too:

```
new_response_url(id: @some_id, decision: "agreed", only_path: false)
```

In this case the generated URL [will have protocol and hostname prefix](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-with-url-for) specified in `default_url_options` config option.

Comment: I have my heroku app url there. so if I change it from `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'rails-app.herokuapp.com' }` to `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com' }` it should be okay?

Comment: Yes, + specify `only_path: false` option in your URL for any case.